# Auto populate sticker and print multiple

Tags: vb.net, printing

I have a table of information that corresponds to the details I would like to print out on a generic sticker. So lets say the sticker has Name, Last Name, Employee Number and my table has 10 rows with indicating there are 10 employees. I will open the dialog page for print and i wasnt to select the printer, after the printer is selected, i want it to take the saved values from each row print a label with each employees information.

Currently I have programmed just regular printing and creating a table of information. I am just wondering how the print loop would go, i think it should be something like this:

```
   Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click 
    PrintDialog1.Document = PrintDocument1

    PrintDialog1.PrinterSettings = PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings



    If PrintDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then

        PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = True
        For Each row In Table1
            Employeename.Text = NameRow
            Employeelastname.text = LastNameRow
            EnployeeNumber.text = EmployeeNumberCell
            PrintDocument1.Print()
        Next

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: In the physical printer, is it one sticker per page or multiple? If multiple, how many per page?

Comment: No, this is one sticker per page, it would just be multiple pages with one sticker each

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the name suggests, the `PrintPage` event of the `PrintDocument` prints a page. If you want to print multiple pages, you need to raise that event multiple times. You do that by setting the `e.HasMorePages` property to `True` in the event handler when there are more pages to print. Here's a simple example of printing one record per page from a `DataTable`:

```vb
'The data to be printed.
Private table As DataTable

'The index of the row to print.
Private rowIndex As Integer

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Start printing at the first row.
    rowIndex = 0

    'Print the data.
    PrintDocument1.Print()
End Sub

Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    'Get the current row.
    Dim row = table.Rows(rowIndex)

    'Print the current row.
    e.Graphics.DrawString(row.Field(Of String)("SomeColumn"), Me.Font, Brushes.Black, 50, 50)

    rowIndex += 1

    'Print another page if and only if there is another row to be printed.
    e.HasMorePages = rowIndex < table.Rows.Count
End Sub
```

You can modify the actual printing code in the `PrintPage` event handler to print whatever data you want in whatever layout you want. If you have multiple values to print then you make multiple calls to `e.Graphics.DrawX` methods. If it's all text you want to print then it will be all `DrawString` calls, but you have `DrawImage` for printing images and `DrawRectangle`, etc, for printing shapes.

Comment: One question I do have is when you use the private table as datatable how can I have this be the most recent version of my datatable? I technically retrieve the data from a database using a different function, but every time I print, it shows the previous datatable values that was saved!

Comment: You're asking how variables work. The variable ALWAYS contains the last value you assigned to it. Just assign to it whatever `DataTable` you want the contents of to be printed. If you have a method that populates a new `DataTable`, assign that new `DataTable` to the variable. This is one of the absolute fundamentals of programming in any language and not something that should have to be explained here.

Comment: ok, I understand that, this wasnt really my question but alright.